# How to use multiple keytabs with spark-submit, so as to connect to multiple kerberized services?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, kerberos

The use case is to connect to kerberized YARN/HDFS and KAFKA services from spark streaming application, with each service being in different realms.

How to construct the spark-submit command so as to pass the multiple keytabs?

**Previous implementations :**

- --keytab,--principal used for YARN/HDFS keytab file and principal value
- -Djava.security.auth.login.config=jaas.conf and -Djava.security.krb5.conf=krb5.conf for KAFKA client configs.
- spark.hadoop.fs.hdfs.impl.disable.cache=true

**Result :** ticket doesn't get renewed automatically after the expiry period for YARN/HDFS

**Error :** HDFS_DELEGATION_TOKEN expired

If cross-realm trust is implemented, how will be the single keytab used for both the services (HDFS/YARN as well as KAFKA) with spark-submit command ?

Comment: The keytab is used to get the initial TGT (Ticket-Granting Ticket); then the TGT is used to obtain any service ticket you need. If the service is located in a different realm then the Kerberos client uses `krb5.conf` to know the "CA path" between source and target relms - by default it follows a hierarchical path e.g. `USERS.EUROPE.ORG` to `EUROPE.ORG` to `ORG` to `DATACENTER1.ORG`. Provided all the intermediate realms are defined in the conf (or can be resolved by DNS).

Comment: But... Spark does not work that way. It does not manage a TGT for each driver/executor process; the "client" bootstraps Hadoop auth tokens at launch then forwards them to driver & executors. No extra Kerberos auth is possible **unless** you run in _client_ mode > the driver resides in the same JVM as the "client" > the driver has direct access to the TGT _(but not the executors...)_

Comment: Maybe you need to push keytabs to each executor, run custom code at executor startup to manage custom Kerberos creds. Good luck with that, Kerberos is a nightmare - and until recently there was no way to run custom code at executor startup in a reliable way, so you need a pretty recent version to experiment that trick.